# Each method in rails acts different when Model.all from Model.find_by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When I get my @variables with:

```
@variables = Variable.all
```

I can do

```
@variables.each do |variable|
```

just fine, but when I get it with the find_by, like so:

```
@variables = Variable.find_by_user_id(user.id)
```

I get an **each method not found error**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The find_by_field methods return a single record, which you can't iterate over.

What you want is

```
Variable.where(:user_id => user.id)
```

or

```
Variable.find_all_by_user_id(user.id)
```

or (assuming you have an association set up properly)

```
user.variables
```